# how to use window.matchMedia in next.js with style components theme?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, media-queries, styled-components

I have a theme:

```
const smartPhonePortrait = 320;


const theme = {
  isCompact:
    typeof window !== 'undefined'
      ? window.matchMedia(`(min-width:${smartPhonePortrait}px)`).matches
      : false
};

export default theme;
```

And then I add this theme to my provider

inside of _app.js:

```
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import theme from '../theme';

const App = ({ Component, pageProps, router }) => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
     ... my app
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

and in my styled component I do this:

```
const Item = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: ${(props) => (props.theme.isCompact ? '100%' : '48%')};
`;
```

This works on first render but when I change screen size it does not update.
If im in mobile I get `flex-basis 100%` but if I change the screen size to desktop I dont get `48%`

How do I make it work?

Comment: The `(min-width: 320px)` media query will still be true for desktop screen sizes. You need to create a different query to match desktop screen sizes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could do is make a hook:

```
import { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
const useMediaQuery = (width) => {
  const [targetReached, setTargetReached] = useState(false);

  const updateTarget = useCallback((e) => {
    if (e.matches) {
      setTargetReached(true);
    } else {
      setTargetReached(false);
    }
  }, [setTargetReached]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      const media = window.matchMedia(`(max-width: ${width}px)`);
      media.addEventListener('change', updateTarget);

      if (media.matches) {
        setTargetReached(true);
      }

      return () => media.removeEventListener('change', updateTarget);
    }
  }, []);

  return targetReached;
};

export default useMediaQuery;
```

and in your `__app.js` you import it and add it to your theme:

```
import MediaQuery from 'hooks/useMedia';

const isCompact = MediaQuery(576);
const useTheme = { ...theme, isCompact };

<ThemeProvider theme={useTheme}>
  ... my app
</ThemeProvider>
```

Comment: addListener and removeListener is deprecated, you can use `addEventListener('change', updateTarget)` now.